# My HP wireless capable printer tells me it is connected to my home network, however will not print

Tags: wireless-networking, printing

My home WiFi network is working fine, however my hp printer indicates that it is connected to my wireless network but the indicator lamp is not on (it will normally have a blue indicator lamp showing) and will not print wireless.

I have been to the Hp website and followed all of the troubleshooting guides with negative results. I am able to print using a USB cable.

This problem only began within the last 48 hours.The printer is an Hp Photosmart 5520 series all-in-one model. The printer is around 5 to 6 years old.

Any ideas out there, please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to at least ping the printer's IP address? Have you upgraded the Wi-Fi network itself recently?

Comment: What indicates that the printer is connecting to the network?  If the indicator isn't showing, you're getting conflicting information.  On a 5-6 yo printer, the WiFi function could be starting to fail.  HP has also been known to update the software and firmware with "improvements" that aren't always for your benefit, and not always without side effects.  I don't know what the troubleshooting guide includes, but a few things to try: 1. Shut off the printer, unplug the power cord, leave it that way for at least a minute, plug the power cord back in, and turn on the printer.  (cont'd)

Comment: Check whether WiFi works.  2. Set up the printer's WiFi again from scratch, as you did when it was new (if there was a separate WiFi setup).  3. Instead of letting the router randomly assign it an IP address, go into the router settings and manually assign it a fixed address at the high end of the range.  Then use that IP address in the printer settings on each computer.

Comment: The printer has a touch screen which tells me I am connected to my wifi. This is located in the upper left hand corner of the touch screen. The wifi indicator  I  refer to in my previous post is located in the right upper corner showing a small antenna with a small blue indicator light. This indicator would always be lighted showing a constant blue light. This is not happening. you mention that the wifi function could be failing, this indeed may be the case. However, before trashing the printer and purchasing a new unit I wanted to get some other opinions and advice. Thank you